# Signing Certs - python-cryptography library behavior changes between versions

Tags: python, ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, ca

I'm using the [Cryptography 1.0](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library for python to sign SSL certificates with our company's CA. This [snippet](https://code.compassfoundation.io/snippets/1) illustrates the code I'm using.

In version 1.0, the snippet produces a correctly signed certificate, but when I upgrade any newer version (including 1.0.1), the certificate hierarchy is flat, as you'd expect with a self-signed certificate. The issuer details on the Details tab, is the same, however. But of course the status of the cert signed by 1.7.1 is "The issuer of this certificate could not be found."

The only variation is the cryptography version. Same python, same system, same OpenSSL library.

[image: Cert detail comparison]

I've reviewed the [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) docs, and I can't see what changed in the newer versions. Anyone have sharper eyes?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bug in cryptography; filed at [#3515](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3515).